# In Starcraft 2 replays, can you display the army, supply, minerals collected rate graphs vs time?

Tags: starcraft-2

**In Starcraft 2 replays, can you display the army, supply, minerals-collected-rate graphs vs time? If yes, how?**

I know you can view the instantaneous resource collection rates or the instantaneous army supply. But I would like to see graphs like you do in the "Score Screen".

[image: demonstration of the graph i have seen]

Comment: Definitely saw graphs in the YouTube video. Hmm. But... YouTube might be a live recording instead of replay. So maybe it's an observer thing.